# jQuery-ui tabs character encoding problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, character-encoding

Swedish characters get substituted when setting the tabTemplate option.

For example using "ö" in the href:

```
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'tabTemplate', '<li><a href="#ö">#{label}</a></li>');
```

becomes:

```
<li><a href="#%C3%B6">ö</a></li>
```

Comment: Why is that a problem?  It's a URL so it's being urlencoded

Comment: Because when I later try to click that tab it is not selected.

Comment: by not selected, do you mean it does not go there, or do you mean that there is no link under it?

Comment: it doesn't go there. Maybe I could replace the affected characters using regexp but it does seem superfluos ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode is not supported in URLs yet.  They must be encoded.  But no string that is URL-encoded after the hash will not automatically move the scroll bars to where you think it should.  You are going to need JavaScript to find the element you are looking for and scroll it into view.

Use `unescape` to get the characters. Then find the element using jQuery, as you are already used to. Get the actual DOM element (using jQuery's `get` function), and call `scrollIntoView` on it.